# Merge Query Performance - Unique Constraint or Indexing?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, constraints, cypher

I am pushing 2K+ nodes and 8k+ edges to the Graph, which is taking approximately 7000ms. And, further I will be working with 100k+ Nodes and relationships. My query uses Merge operation in this way:

```
MERGE (a:User){user:'username'}
MERGE (b:Hobby){hobby:'hobby'}
MERGE (a)-[r:Hobby]->(b)
```

> Note: username and hobby are strings in the query

Now, I am trying to improve the performance of the query. To do so, after googling, I came to know two ways.

1. Indexing on the node properties username and hobby. So that, the merge 
      operation will boost in performance.
2. CREATE Constraint on node properties username and hobby. Many people
      suggesting this method.

My questions are:

1. What is the difference between Indexing a property and Creating constraint 
      on a property? How Graph deals with these(like what it do internally) operations?
2. Which is the right way to do improve the performance?

Edit:

My code:

```
session = driver.session()
session.run('CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:user) ASSERT u.user IS UNIQUE')
session.run('CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (h:hobby) ASSERT h.hobby IS UNIQUE')

session.close()

def writeBatch(b):
    print("writing batch of " + str(len(b)))
    session = driver.session()
    session.run('UNWIND {batch} AS elt '+
                'MERGE (u:user{user: elt.user})'+
                'MERGE (h:hobby{hobby:elt.hobby})'+
                'MERGE (u)-[r:hobby]->(h)'
                +'', {'batch': b})
    session.close()
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adaggula/Documents/workspace2/Facebook/FbNeo.py", line 145, in <module>
    userhobby.foreach(write2neo)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 747, in foreach
    self.mapPartitions(processPartition).count()  # Force evaluation
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1004, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 995, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 869, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 771, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2379, in _jrdd
    pickled_cmd, bvars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(self.ctx, command, self)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2299, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 428, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 646, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 107, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 633, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 633, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 633, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 633, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 636, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 636, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 193, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 241, in save_function_tuple
    save(f_globals)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 193, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 241, in save_function_tuple
    save(f_globals)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 686, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 524, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 636, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 686, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 315, in save_builtin_function
    return self.save_function(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 191, in save_function
    if islambda(obj) or obj.__code__.co_filename == '<stdin>' or themodule is None:
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__code__'
16/09/20 16:35:22 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Answer (score 2):

## Index vs constraint

An index is a fast means of finding nodes which indexed property have a certain value, replacing a sequential scan of all the nodes (instead of an *O(n)* algorithm, you usually get *O(log(n))*). Many nodes can have the property with the same value.

A constraint is a way of enforcing a schema on the data. There are 2 types of constraints on nodes in Neo4j:

1. Property unicity:

   ```
   CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) ASSERT n.uuid IS UNIQUE;
   ```
2. Property existence:

   ```
   CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) ASSERT exists(n.name);
   ```

As it happens, the unicity constraint uses an index to quickly find if another node already uses the same value.

So a label with a unicity constraint also has an index on the property, but a label with an index on a property does not require unicity.

## Which one should I use?

Since you're using `MERGE` to find or create the `User` and `Hobby` nodes, the properties are obviously unique. You should definitely use a unicity constraint to enforce the schema, instead of simply having an index.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:User) ASSERT n.user IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Hobby) ASSERT n.hobby IS UNIQUE;
```

Comment: if islambda(obj) or obj.__code__.co_filename == '<stdin>' or themodule is None:
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__code__'

Comment: Throwing this error. I am using sessions in neo4j.vi driver. I have created the constraints in one session before any data pushed. And then, I am pushing the the data as batches.

Comment: Edited my Question with the code I used and the error I faced @ Frank Pavageau

Comment: When unique constraints are defined, MERGE expects to find at most one node that matches the pattern  http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/07/31/cypher-merge-explained.html

Comment: I typoed `CREATE INDEX` instead of `CREATE CONSTRAINT` in my last 2 lines. You seem to have fixed it in your code, but it doesn't match the error message.

Comment: Yep. I corrected in my query. And Re edited the question with complete error message

Comment: Ah well, that's a pure Python error now, I'm afraid I can't help you with that.

Comment: Okk. I will ask it as a new question. Thanks.